# Matching from last instance of character if present to validate filename with extension in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to limit the user from uploading `Long named files` and `unaccepted file extensions` using a regular expression validator in Asp.net 2.0 Webforms. I wanted the `filename to be withing 30` characters[restriction due to Db Design] and extensions match `png,jpeg,zip,rar,7z`.I came up with this regular expression which makes sure filename is valid character and then comes `.` literal period then the extension.

`^[\w_]{3,28}\.(pdf|jpeg|png)$`

**Update:**
i came up with this regex that matches even last instance only that even long filenames get validated

```
(\\(?!.*\\)|)[\w_]{3,30}\.(pdf|jpeg|jpg|pdf)$
```

**Update:** Even this works just that fileName does not get limited to 30 characters

```
[\w]{3,30}\.(pdf|jpeg|jpg|pdf)(?=)
```

**info:** It even validated `c:\fakePath\stackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflow` btw it highlighted last 30 characters in fileName.

The problem was that i want the validation to be done on client at time of uploading hence `EnableClientScript = True` , but to my surprise the fileUpload.value which the control validates was totally different in most of the browsers.

Firefox reports: filename.extension as expected,

Internet Explorer reported the Full Path to File

chrome reports C:\fakePath\fileName.extension

Now how do i write a expression for this, my idea was to look for last instance of the `\` character if present in the value then begin form there. But my knowledge of Regex is totally limited to the basics. could someone correct me and provide a working regex,

**Note:**
Pls , before providing one make sure it met my requirements, works cross browser and validates on clientSide.

Comment: `\w` includes the underscore (`_`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
\b\w{3,30}\.(?:pdf|jpe?g|png|7z|zip|rar)$
```

This matches a filename starting at a word boundary (without the `\b` it might start the match in the middle of an overlong filename). Only ASCII letters, digits and underscores are allowed in the filename (no accented characters!), dots are also forbidden.

Remember to construct the regex using regex literal notation:

```
var myregexp = /\b\w{3,30}\.(?:pdf|jpe?g|png|7z|zip|rar)$/;
```

Comment: @Tim doesn't validate value on chrome `c:\fakePath\hgshdgdhfgdshfgdshgfhdsgfhdsgjfhsgf.pdf` even on Ie i suppose

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Well, it shouldn't, should it? It's longer than 30 characters. How are you constructing the regex? Using a string or a regex object?

Comment: @Tim even though value is `c:\fakePath\hgshdgdhfgdshfgdshgfhdsgfhdsgjfhsgf.pdf` i would like regex to check from last instance of `\` hence in above it would checked `hgshdgdhfgdshfgdshgfhdsgfhdsgj.pdf` which is 30 chars and i tested it like below `"c:\fakepath\hgshdgdhfgdshfgdshgfhdsgfhdsgj.pdf".match(/\b\w{3,30}\.(?:pdf|jpe?g|png|7z|zip|rar)$/);`

Comment: @Tim i tested the regex on http://regexpal.com/ and it works cross browser.  Is there a fundamental difference between test, match in string and Regex Object in javascript?

Comment: In a string you generally need to escape the backslashes (not just in regexes; you seem to have forgotten that in your example - `C:\fakepath` is interpreted as `C:`, formfeed, `akepath`).

Comment: @Tim and to my surprise the validator validates using string validation in asp.net server controls `\\b\\w{3,30}\\.(?:pdf|jpe?g|png|7z|zip|rar|txt|doc|docx)$` so this is how it gets transformed from your explanation ? would it work even then?? because it's not on my side :(

Comment: @Tim i tried `"deeptechtons.pdf".match(/\\b\\w{3,30}\\.(?:pdf|jpe?g|png|7z|zip|rar|txt|doc|docx)$/);` and it fails the match what can i do now?

Comment: No,no: You need to escape the backslashes only if you construct the regex from a string! In a regex literal (`/regex.../`) single backslashes are sufficient. I suggest a look at [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Comment: @tim thanks for your time. btw this problem was all caused by the Script Written by Microsoft which isn't cross browser.`function RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val) {
    var value = ValidatorGetValue(val.controltovalidate);
    if (ValidatorTrim(value).length == 0)
        return true;
    var rx = new RegExp(val.validationexpression);
    var matches = rx.exec(value);
    return (matches != null && value == matches[0]);
}
`